# Getting highly inconsistent results on retraining models on same dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am training a CNN for image watermarking. I have a dataset of 12k images. I am getting inconsistent results on same dataset on retraining, sometimes model is performing very well but other times it's worse by many magnitudes.
Implementation is done in Keras.Here is the original paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.02460

```
"""
ARCHITECTURE
"""

def Convolution_Block(input_tensor):
    # Branch 1
    branch1 = Conv2D(32, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=he_uniform())(input_tensor)

    # Branch 2
    branch2 = Conv2D(32, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=he_uniform())(input_tensor)
    branch2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=he_uniform())(branch2)

    # Branch 3
    branch3 = Conv2D(32, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=he_uniform())(input_tensor)
    branch3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=he_uniform())(branch3)
    branch3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=he_uniform())(branch3)

    concat_output = Concatenate(axis=-1)([branch1, branch2, branch3])

    final_output = Conv2D(input_tensor.shape[-1], (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=he_uniform())(concat_output)
    # Add the original input to the output
    final_output = Add()([final_output, input_tensor])
    return final_output


# Model Flow

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# First Large Block (Watermark Preprocessing) (Encoder mu-theta-1)

# Taking watermark input
watermark = Input(shape=(32, 32, 1))


conv_block_x2A = Convolution_Block(watermark)
conv_block_x2A = Convolution_Block(conv_block_x2A)


conv2d_1x1x24 = Conv2D(24, (1, 1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=he_uniform())(conv_block_x2A)

conv_block_x2B = Convolution_Block(conv2d_1x1x24)
conv_block_x2B = Convolution_Block(conv_block_x2B)

conv2d_1x1x48 = Conv2D(48, (1, 1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=he_uniform())(conv_block_x2B)  # outuput wfi

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Second Large Block (Input Preprocessing & watermark Concatenation) (Embedder sigma-theta-2)


cover_images = Input(shape=cover_image_shape)

reshaped_watermark = Reshape((128,128,3))(conv2d_1x1x48)

conv_block_x1A = Convolution_Block(reshaped_watermark) 

concatenated_output = Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv_block_x1A, cover_images])

conv_block_x1B = Convolution_Block(concatenated_output)

conv2d_1x1x3 = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=he_uniform())(conv_block_x1B)  # output mi


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Third Large Block (Fully Connected Dense Layer) (Invariance Introduction) (Channel Coding) (Invariance tau-theta-5)
invariance = Dense(N)
invariance_output = invariance(conv2d_1x1x3)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Decoder

# Fourth Large Block (Extractor psi-theta-3)

conv_block_x2C = Convolution_Block(invariance_output)
conv_block_x2C = Convolution_Block(conv_block_x2C)

conv2d_1x1x3B = Conv2D(3, (1, 1))(conv_block_x2C)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Fifth Large Block (Decoder gamma-theta-4)
conv2d_1x1x3B = Reshape((32,32,48))(conv2d_1x1x3B)

conv_block_x2D = Convolution_Block(conv2d_1x1x3B)
conv_block_x2D = Convolution_Block(conv_block_x2D)

conv2d_1x1x24B = Conv2D(24, (1, 1))(conv_block_x2D)

conv_block_x2E = Convolution_Block(conv2d_1x1x24B)
conv_block_x2E = Convolution_Block(conv_block_x2E)

conv2d_1x1x1 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1))(conv_block_x2E)



model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[watermark, cover_images], outputs=[conv2d_1x1x1, conv2d_1x1x3, invariance_output])
```

I did not expect this much sensitivity, is this normal? if so, how can researchers make sure that their results are reproducible. I have tried to make results more deterministic by setting seeds to every random thing I could (keras functions, np functions, random module and data generators), and some seeds do give the good results while others do bad. I have tried different initializers including he and Xavier all are similar. Also tried setting various learning rates and scheduling all to no avail, sometimes it works exceptionally in lr's as small as 0.001 but other times gets stuck in local minimums at 5x the learning rates. I am a deep learning novice; any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is too vague to answer, or to even say if its normal or not. Maybe you are doing something wrong, but we cannot say without code.

Comment: I have added my code in the post and linked the paper I am trying to implement.